# Project Explorer showing only "src" folders instead of projects

Tags: eclipse

I haven't used Eclipse in a while; the problem is related to either a silent auto-update or installing Python in a separate workspace.

[image]

Using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 4.18.0 (20201210-1552).

Comment: Did you try Window -> Close All Perspectives and Window -> Open Perspective?

Comment: That actually worked. Thank you. May have been related to Eclipse silently auto-updating, since I haven't launched it in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, to fix the problem go to windows then close all perspectives and open perspectives again.